# Broadcasting a message to multiple workers spring rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-batch

I am using RabbitMQ with Spring.  I have multiple workers running on separate vm's that pick up messages in a round robin fashion.  All is good.

Now, I would like to declare one queue "command" where ALL the workers process messages sent to that queue.  So I want this command to be run on ALL the worker/listeners.

Is it possible to set this up using RabbitMQ/Spring?
I saw one solution where each work setup their own queue for processing, but that is not ideal for me.

So, I would essentially like to broadcast a message to a single queue and have all the workers process the message.

Thanks for any help.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

> I would essentially like to broadcast a message to a single queue and
>   have all the workers process the message.

Create a [fanout exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html). A publish subscribe feature where all the messages would be pushed to a single queue & received by all the subscriber workers.